# Microsoft OneNote Replacement

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I'm wondering if a free, open source replacement for Microsoft OneNote exists.

Features it would need to have:

- Click anywhere on the page and start typing.
- Automatic revision history tracking.
- Some sort of basic drawing facility (circle text, draw extremely crude diagrams, etc.)

Not being platform-specific would be great too.

Does anyone use or know of any project that fits the bill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/)?  Works on Mac, PC, iPhone, and has a web interface...it has has a free version that works very well for most users, but not open-source.  Highly recommend...

Comment: I'll have to try it.

Comment: Downvoting only to reflect that original request is not fulfilled by this answer where it asks for *free, open source replacement ...*. Evernote is neither open source, nor free. (Running long-term, in total costs it might be even more expensive than the OneNote – just check monthly pricing.)

Comment: It was free, at least five years ago? Consider the original date of post, @miroxlav, before downvoting. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @studiohack – thank you for feedback. Evernote is on subscription model since **June 2008**, what can be still found on their [Evernote Public Launch blog post, June 24, 2008](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2008/06/24/evernote-public-launch/). People often think of it as free (even if it has paid option) but I have friends who exhausted free quota relatively fast (using various forms of image-based notes) and discovered they can go nowhere without paying. This is why I sometimes make notes about total cost of ownership of Evernote account.

Comment: @miroxlav: Thanks for explaining! I admit that when I used it, I didn't use it enough to max out, so I didn't really personally realize how easy/hard it would be to max out. Thanks for clarifying! Seeing as this is the only answer and is *somewhat* true, I'll leave it. But your comment is relevant, so +1 and thanks.